# Windows Server 2008 R2 FTP Connection failing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, windows-firewall, iis

I have looked all over and I am sorry if this is a double post somewhere.

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that sits behind a Cisco ASA. It has the latest patches and all Windows firewalls are OFF.

I went through the FTP site setup wizard and assigned the IP address to servers static IP (ex. 10.4.2.1) and gave it a host name of ftp.example.com. I set the appropriate folder location as well.

I have it set for Anonymous access and have a user/password setup for the Anonymous access account.

I restart the server from IIS Manager and then ping ftp.example.com and I get the server local IP, as I should since I am internal

When I open IE on the server and go to ftp.example.com it says it cannot connect. I have done this on other servers in the past, and it has always connected and should connect on the local network.

I need it to prompt for user credentials, for example if I go to our other site, ftp.example.fr in France, I am prompted with a login window.

I cannot for the life of me figure why it will not connect, on a local network, to the ftp site I created.

I hope I explained this well enough. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking here. 1. You're saying you setup Anonymous access, but then you say you need it to prompt for a user name and password. 2. You say you can access this internally, but you can't access it from a server. Is that server internal also? Lets start from the place you're having the issue from. Double check your troubleshooting steps from there, DNS resolution (Internal or Extneral) is a best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

*is it accessable from the inside?
*does nslookup resolve your static nat address for the outside world?
*10.0.0.1 is uaually used as a gateway ip address unless you assinged your gateway to something else.
*does your ASA permit http and ftp?

if you set the server up correctly, then the issue is either ip, dns, or access-list

Comment: Thanks for the response... I used 10.0.0.1 as an example.. I realize now I should have used something else and will change in the original post. nslookup does resolve to the correct IP on the inside, but does not reflect the outside IP. As far as I know, the ASA is configured correctly, although you have given me a place to start

Comment: cool! glad to be of help, sorry i couldnt be more precise for you though. reply back with more information and i can try to help you out a littl more.